# Build is succeded but Error in real device, 'Unable to install "APP name"' Code: -402620415

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

My flutter app runs well in Android(device and simulator both)

But in iOS there is an error.

The build and run both are succeded on simulator, but does not run on real device.

```
Unable to install "APP name"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620415
--
An unknown error has occurred.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402620415
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 280331;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8008001)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011da4b3b8 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011da89ae1 __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106b23b7c DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011da89822 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1440
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000115dc7999 __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.294 + 3534
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106c56931 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x0000000106c5855b __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 1191
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204425dd _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204437c7 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff204495fe _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 606
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff2044a0cb _dispatch_lane_invoke + 375
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff20453c5d _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 819
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff205eb499 _pthread_wqthread + 314
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff205ea467 start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.2.3 (Build 20D91)
Xcode 12.5 (18205) (Build 12E262)
Timestamp: 2021-05-24T11:58:07+09:00
```

I searched on google, stack overflow, apple... and tried to figure it out. but I can't

What I tired is

1. pod install, reinstall
2. delet # in # platform :ios, '9.0'
3. update packages..
4. check singing&Capabilities
5. using another iPhone
6. using another usb cable
7. install lastest Xcode, flutter, dart

.... but still can't fix..

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

setting the build configuration from debug to release and that installed the app again. Changed it back to debug and now it's running again as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But it seems not work...

I changed

1) Debug Yes -> No, 2) Release No -> Yes

in Architectrues in Build setting